# How to build a large docker image with relatively small disk space consumption?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

**Background**

I am trying to build a docker image from Dockerfile on a VM. VM is running Redhat 7.1 (kernel 3.10) and Docker is 1.10.2

The Dockerfile has following content

```
FROM rhel
MAINTAINER MyName<me@email.com>
RUN #yum install wget and other tools (less than 500 MB)
COPY entitlementfile /opt/entitlementfile
RUN  wget -O /opt/installer.bin https://installer.com/installer.bin \ 
    && chmod +x /opt/* \
    && /opt/installer.bin --quiet \
    && rm -f /opt/*.bin
USER admin
```

My build VM has around **16G** space available

```
[root@xrh701 DockerImage]# df -h
Filesystem                                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel-root                              18G  2.1G   16G  12% /
...
```

The installer is around **3G** and the installed package is around **8G**. This adds up to 11G maximum, slightly exceeds docker defaults base device size which is 10G.

So I manually bring up docker daemon with a larger dm.size (**15G**) to work around this issue.

```
docker daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=15G
```

Since docker is based on Union FS, the images are layered on top of each other.
So my understanding is that

(1) the maximum size that my image could get is 11G (Installer in one layer 3G, and the package layer added on top 8G)

(2) and if I wget the installer, run it, then delete the installer in the same RUN command, the image should only be 8G ( since 3G installer is deleted)

Either way, the bottom line is, 16G space should be more than enough.

**Problem**

But my current observation is that during my docker build process,
it would always hang since it had consumed all the available spaces

```
[root@xrh701 DockerImage]# df -h
Filesystem                                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel-root                              18G   18G   20K 100% /
...
```

I can see two images

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              fa09e98656ba        About an hour ago   258.1 MB
rhel                latest              32f8a1d5f019        9 days ago          203.2 MB
```

"docker inspect " shows that the < none > image is the intermediate image after COPY the entitlement file.

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
232245023f90        fa09e98656ba        "/bin/sh -c 'wget -O "   About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                       lonely_curie
```

This intermediate container has completed the RUN wget line, exited successfully, but did not commit to docker image due to lack of space

What's worse, I cannot remove the container nor delete /var/lib/docker to restore the space back

```
# docker rm -f lonely_curie
Failed to remove container (lonely_curie): Error response from daemon: Driver devicemapper failed to remove root filesystem 232245023f90b42a4dbd19a78bf32836f9f8618d7dbcba54159c3df029b5b114: mount still active
```

**Question**

1. Why has docker used up all the space? According to the calculation, the disk space (16G) should be more than enough for the target image (8G). [I own this VM so I can guarantee no one else or any other process is consuming hard disk space ]
2. How do I force remove the container in  my current situation so I can restore the space back?
3. How should I build this 8G image (or 11G image if you count the installer) on a 16G VM? If this is not possible, what is the minimum space to successfully build it? I am currently applying for a 32G VM from the lab.

Comment: Hmm, it seems the lonely_curie is removed, since I can't see it in `docker ps -a` anymore... but I still can't remove /var/lib/docker as it still complains device and resource busy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Assume the installer is 3G and the installed package is 8G.

If I release the Dokcerfile, then the minimum disk requirement would be at least 22 G [ (3+8)*2 = 22 ] to build this image.

If I release the image and have pushed to Dockerhub, then user only needs 11 G to pull the image and run a container based on it.

==================================================================

**Build**

I got a machine about 50G in size to rerun the build and monitored the disk consumption.

Before the build starts

```
# df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_01-lv_root   59G   6G   53G  9% /
...
```

After the installation has completed

```
# df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_01-lv_root   59G   19G   38G  34% /
...
```

After the image is commited

```
# df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_01-lv_root   59G   27G   30G  48% /
...
```

So to answer my own question:
(1) It used up all the disk because it requires at least that much disk space. Previous calculation had wishfully assumed the running container and image to be built will share the same layer.

(2) Haven't figure out this part yet. Right now I am just throwing away the VM and let the reclaim it.

(3) The minimum disk required would be (3G + 8G) * 2 = 22 G. So I guess for future reference, I should reserve twice as much of theoretically calculated image size, since the layer seems to be a copied instead of shared when committing a running container to a image. [Building a Dockerfile is essentially the same as the manually running a container and committing to image.]

=================================================================

**Run**

And to follow up, after I commit the image and delete the container, the disk can be reclaimed

```
# df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_01-lv_root   59G   15G   42G  26% /
....
```

And from then on, bringing up a running container will not increase the disk consumption (significantly).

```
# df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_01-lv_root   59G   15G   42G  26% /
...
```